# socket.io like for Python 2.7 + Bottle framework

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, bottle

I am developing my web app with `Python 2.7 + Bottle`. Everything is great and python is an amazing language coming from ASP.NET. I am building a web application that needs to use real-time client/server communication and socket.io for node.js comes to mind.

I wanted to know how can I implement socket.io-like using Python + bottle. I've read this article [on bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html), but I can't still seem to understand how it works - what I need to install, and how all works out (code examples?).

I really need that for my next web application but need help in understanding what I need to put in my project in order for it to work. I have no problem working with 'preview' codes which aren't stable release yet. I'm developing on Windows platform. Thanks.

I also want to know if its scalabe. whether I can use redis in the back so all calls will be sync when running my website on several servers, so when one client send data, all the other clients connected to the other servers will get it to.

Answer (score 1):

maybe websocket can help you,many modern browser support this protocol,but bottle.py don't support it now,you can get some idea from [tornado.websocket](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/websocket.py) and [some answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316374/bottle-websocket?rq=1)

cause every connection can be saved,so i guess it can run on several servers,but i never implement.

since bottle is micro framework,you should do something by yourself.