# Bottle server with WebSocket (without other third-party libraries)

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, wsgi, bottle

I have read [Bottle + WebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316374/bottle-websocket) and the Github project [`bottle-websocket`](https://github.com/zeekay/), but they all use `gevent`, or other third party tools.

Question: nowadays (2023), **is there a way to do a simple Bottle + WebSocket hello world example, without any third party tool?**

This is a beginning but it fails (see JS console) with:

> (index):12 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:5000/ws' failed

```
import bottle, random
app = bottle.Bottle()
@bottle.route("/")
def index():
    return bottle.static_file("index.html", root=".")
@bottle.route("/ws")
def ws():
    wsock = bottle.request.environ.get('wsgi.websocket')
    if not wsock:
        print('Expected WebSocket request.')
    while True:
        try:
            message = wsock.receive()
            wsock.send("Your message was: %r" % message)
        except:
            break
bottle.run(threaded=False, port=5000, debug=True)
```

HTML+JS code for `index.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    hello
</div>
<script>
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5000/ws");
ws.onopen = () => {
    ws.send("Hello, world");
 };
ws.onmessage = (evt) => {
    console.log(evt.data);
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but in case it's helpful, I'll mention FastAPI (which supports websockets natively and is well documented): https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/

Answer (score 3):

"without any third party tool?": unlikely.

In your Python script, you're trying to access a WebSocket object (`wsgi.websocket`) from the WSGI (Web Server Gateway Interface) environment. However, the WSGI standard does not natively support WebSockets, and the Bottle web framework adheres to the WSGI standard. This means that it cannot handle WebSocket connections without additional tools that provide WebSocket support, such as `gevent-websocket`.

The error message `(index):12 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:5000/ws' failed` is a result of this issue. The WebSocket connection request is made to the `/ws` route, but since Bottle does not support WebSockets, it does not know how to handle this request, so the connection fails.

---

If you want to create a WebSocket server in Python without any third-party libraries, you would typically use the [`websockets` module in the Python standard library](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). However, Bottle does not natively support WebSockets, and the Python standard library does not include a WebSocket server or client.

Implementing WebSockets involves handling upgrade requests, managing connection state, and parsing and constructing WebSocket frames, which is non-trivial. Therefore, it's typically done using third-party libraries like `gevent-websocket` for Bottle, or `websockets` or [`aiohttp` for Python](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) in general.

It is theoretically possible to implement WebSocket support directly in a Bottle application by manually handling the HTTP upgrade request and then the WebSocket frames. However, this would essentially involve reimplementing a significant portion of what these third-party libraries do, and it would be quite complex. It would also likely be less efficient and less robust than using a dedicated WebSocket library.

If you want to avoid using third-party libraries, you might want to consider using a different framework that has built-in WebSocket support.
Like [Flask framework](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/), which has built-in WebSocket support via the [Flask-Sock extension](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-sock), and the [Django framework](https://www.djangoproject.com/), which has built-in WebSocket support via Django Channels. There's also [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/middleware/), a lightweight ASGI framework that has native WebSocket support.

In any case, if you want to implement WebSockets in a Bottle application without using any third-party libraries, you would likely need to do a significant amount of low-level network programming, and you would need a deep understanding of the WebSocket protocol and how it interacts with the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm ok to migrate to Flask, but even in this case, it seems it also requires a third party extension (the Flask-Sock you mentioned). I always want to highly minimize the number of tools and third-party extensions, because it's always a burden on the long term (some extensions are not maintainted anymore, etc.). If I have to replace Bottle by something else, which one would be WebSockets-ready ?

Comment: @Basj I believe (not teste) Starlette (ideal for building high-performance microservices), like FastAPI, has built-in support for WebSockets without requiring any additional libraries or extensions.